# How can I have ansible restart the ssh session after installing nvm?

Tags: vagrant, ansible

nvm requires that a user logs out / back in after installation for the changes to take effect. How can I allow for this in an ansible task running via vagrant. here's what I tried:

```
- name : Install nvm
  shell: curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.1/install.sh | bash
  failed_when: False
  register: nvm_installed

- name: Kill open ssh sessions - ansible should log back in on next task
  shell: "ps -ef | grep sshd | grep `whoami` | awk '{print \"kill -9\", $2}' | sh"
  when: nvm_installed | changed
  failed_when: false

- name : Install Node.js v 4.2.x
  command : nvm install v4.2
```

But I get the error:

```
fatal: [default] => SSH Error: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
    while connecting to 127.0.0.1:2222
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.

TASK: [check if rpmforge installed] ******************************************* 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

the command `vagrant ssh` also now fails with the error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I based this on the answer given here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677064/create-and-use-group-without-restart

I think maybe the kill command is killing the sshd daemon itself?

```
ps -ef | grep sshd | grep `whoami`
root      2621  1247  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 sshd: vagrant [priv]
vagrant   2625  2621  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 sshd: vagrant@notty
root      3232  1247  4 11:34 ?        00:00:00 sshd: vagrant [priv]
vagrant   3235  3232  0 11:34 ?        00:00:00 sshd: vagrant@pts/0
vagrant   3252  3236  0 11:34 pts/0    00:00:00 grep sshd
```

**UPDATE**

I also tried the following:

```
- name : Install nvm
  shell: "curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.1/install.sh | bash"
  register: nvm_installed
  failed_when: False


- name : source bash profiles
  shell : source /home/vagrant/.bashrc
  when: nvm_installed
  register: sourced

- name : Install Node.js v 4.2.x
  command : nvm install v4.2
  when: sourced
```

but get the following error:

```
TASK: [Install Node.js v 4.2.x] *********************************************** 
failed: [default] => {"cmd": "nvm install v4.2", "failed": true, "rc": 2}
msg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/lukemackenzie/playbook.retry

default                    : ok=10   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=1   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

If I run the Install nvm step manually on the managed machine it says that the following has been appended to `.bashrc`:

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/vagrant/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Comment: What if you just `source $HOME/.bashrc $HOME/.bash_profile` instead of logging out?

Comment: It seems like a good option and works when ssh'd into the box but not via ansible (see update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what eventually worked:

```
- name : Install nvm
  shell: curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.1/install.sh | bash
  register: nvm_installed
  sudo: False

- name: Show nvm_installed output
  debug:
    msg: '{{nvm_installed}}'


- name : source bash profiles
  shell: source ~/.bashrc
  args:
     executable: /bin/bash
  register: sourced
  when : nvm_installed | success
  sudo: False


- name: Show sourced output
  debug:
    msg: '{{sourced}}'


- name : Install Node.js v 4.2.x
  shell : '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install v4.2'
  when: sourced|success
  sudo: False
  environment:
    NVM_DIR: /home/vagrant/.nvm
```

It may not be necessary to include the source command as it seems ansible logs in with a non-interactive shell so the contents of `.bashrc` are never picked up.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256884/not-possible-to-source-bashrc-with-ansible

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in the comments sourcing `.profile` should be sufficient for installing `nvm`.

Just replace the sshd restart task with this task:

```
- name: Source bash profile.
  shell: source $HOME/.profile $HOME/.bash_profile
```

You might also want to take a look at this [vagrantfile](https://github.com/robertkowalski/vagrant-nvm/blob/master/provision.sh).

If you need to to restart ssh server (for whatever other reason) you can try this approach as documented in this [Ansible blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910230458/https://support.ansible.com/hc/en-us/articles/201958037-Reboot-a-server-and-wait-for-it-to-come-back):

```
- name : Install nvm
  shell: curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.1/install.sh | bash
  ignore_errors: true
  register: nvm_installed

- name: Kill open ssh sessions - ansible should log back in on next task
  shell: "ps -ef | grep sshd | grep `whoami` | awk '{print \"kill -9\", $2}' | sh"
  async: 0
  poll: 0
  when: nvm_installed | changed

- name: waiting for server to come back
  local_action: wait_for host={{ inventory_hostname }} state=started
        
- name : Install Node.js v 4.2.x
  command : nvm install v4.2
```

Comment: the ```source``` option seems like a good one but I can't get that working (se update)

Comment: The ansible blog post link is broken and/or behind a redhat login wall, but is preserved here on internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20150910230458/https://support.ansible.com/hc/en-us/articles/201958037-Reboot-a-server-and-wait-for-it-to-come-back

Comment: Thanks, updated the link

Answer (score 1):

I created a Galaxy role which will work with Ansible 2: [ssh-reconnect](https://galaxy.ansible.com/udondan/ssh-reconnect/)

Usage:

```
- name : Install nvm
  shell: curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.1/install.sh | bash
  ignore_errors: true
  notify:
    - Kill all ssh connections
```